# How to add NOT NULL constraint to new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add new column `title` to my model with NOT NULL constraint. This is what I tried:

```
class AddTitleColumnToTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :todo_lists, :title, :string, :null => false
  end
end
```

The second variation:

```
class AddTitleColumnToTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :todo_lists, :title, :string, 
    change_column_null :todo_lists, :title, false
  end
end
```

But nothing works. It throws the same error:
`Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL`.
I use SQLite3. What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you are adding a column to an already existing table. When you add this new column and it is not allowed to be `nil`, what do you expect to be the value for already existing records in that table?

Comment: Is it problem to add new column with NOT NULL to existing table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a new column to an already existing table then you cannot add a `NOT NULL` constraint without having a default value or backfill data for all existing records first. Otherwise, all existing records were invalid right away because they all would have `NULL` values in that new column.

A simple solution might be to add something useful to all records before adding the `NOT NULL` constraint.

```
def change
  add_column :todo_lists, :title, :string

  TodoLists.update_all(title: '-')

  change_column_null :todo_lists, :title, false
end
```

Comment: I'd also use raw SQL to not rely on model presence or naming.